# Navigate to related view in IDEA

Tags: spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I use IDEA 13.
Can some help me? When I write code, the count of green icons increase. Their quantity grows and decreases.
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/img/13/spring_javaconfig_small.png - link to a sample icon.  I have a problem with those opposite methods.

Comment: what is the propblem ? they indicate spring beans, assuming you mean the first, icon, the second is to extract an interface (i think).

Comment: When I write code the count of icons increase, i.e. with every word their number is growing in row and window with my code shifts to the right.

Comment: Try invalidating your cache (File > Invalidate caches) and restart. There may be some corruption which is causing IDEA to add additional icons each time it parses the line.

Comment: I tried to invalidate cache, but it did not help.

Comment: Can you post an image of the specific problem?

Comment: Can't, unfortunately I don't have privilege for adding photo.

Answer (score 0):

This is bug my IDEA 13 Ultimate + my Ubuntu 13.04. I installed this same IDEA to Windows 7 and all okay.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you meant "Navigate to related views" icon which had a bug where multiple icons would be rendered while editing http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-118558?